# Bash program terminates after a few seconds

Tags: ssh, rsync, expect

I have written a small script to download files from an FTP to external drive that is connected to my Raspberry Pi 3B+. I am using `rsync` to download my files. Here are the scripts:

download.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo rync -P -r -e ssh user@host:/path/* /local/directory
```

To process password, I have password.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ./download.sh
expect "password: "
send -- "mypassword"
expect eof
```

When I run `password.sh`, it logs into the FTP and file transfer starts, but after 5-6 seconds the program terminates without any error and the file download stops. Is there any way to keep the script running until all downloads are finished? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Try using `interact` instead of `expect eof`, see if that changes anything... You might be hitting an Expect timeout there.

Comment: That is exactly the reason. The script was timing out because it was hitting the except eof. I changed the timeout to -1 and now it works.

Comment: Seriously though, don't use Expect and password authentication here, just use public key authentication in SSH instead. See [ssh-copy-id](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id) for a really easy way to set that up!

Comment: Note: `*` in the Bash script should be quoted. Unquoted `user@host:/path/*` will *probably* never backfire because your local directory structure *most likely* doesn't contain `user@host:/`; but it could.

Comment: I'm noticing that `rsync` is spelt like `rync` in your script. Does this not stop the script from working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man 1 expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect):

> The default timeout period is 10 seconds but may be set, for example to 30, by the command `set timeout 30`. An infinite timeout may be designated by the value `-1`.

You need like `set timeout -1` before `expect eof`.